# Iterating over column values and assigning new values (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe is in a column and looks as follows (column title removed, it is 'test'):

> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ... 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ... 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, etc.
>
> The list recycles to 350000 rows. What I am looking to do is after the item in the list hits 120 and then resets to 1, I would like to continue the list as follows:
>
> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ... 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 121, 122, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123, ... 239, 239, 239, 240, 240, 240, etc.

I am having some trouble with implementing what I am looking to do. The code (which does not work, but I think the logic is close) is below:

```
enter code here

count = 0

for i in c2['test']:

    if i[i-1] == 120 and i == 1: #value previously in column and current value in column
         count += 1 # set multipler to 1 to start, and then as values loop, the counter will get larger
         it = i + (120 * count) # create new value
         c2.set_value(i,'test',it) # set new value; in first instance, this it variable should be 121
    
    if count >= 1:
         iti = i + (120 * count) # create new value
         c2.set_value(i,'test',iti)# set new value; in second instance, this iti variable should be 122
```

Thank you for your help!

**Update:**

When I apply @RafaelC code to my dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h17ssdu7lgwydd9/compiled_training_data.csv?dl=0 the code provided for some reason does not work.

```
dataset_parent_folder = "compiled_training_data.csv"
compiled_data = pd.read_csv(dataset_parent_folder, header=0)
pd.DataFrame(compiled_data).reset_index()
compiled_data.columns = ['test']
MAX = (120*3)+1 #I multiplied by 3 as 3 datasets are merged, and added 1 to get to a target of 360
D = 1 - (MAX-1)
n = compiled_data.test.diff().eq(D).cumsum()*(MAX-1) + compiled_data.test
1180838 rows × 1 columns
```

The output after applying the re-index:

```
test
    1   1
    2   1
    3   1
    4   1
    5   1
    6   1
    7   1
    8   1
    9   1
    10  1
    11  1
    12  1
    13  1
    14  1
    15  1
    16  1
    17  1
    18  1
    19  1
    20  1
    21  1
    22  1
    23  1
    24  1
    25  1
    26  1
    27  1
    28  1
    29  1
    ... ...
    1180808 120
    1180809 120
    1180810 120
    1180811 120
    1180812 120
    1180813 120
    1180814 120
    1180815 120
    1180816 120
    1180817 120
    1180818 120
    1180819 120
    1180820 120
    1180821 120
    1180822 120
    1180823 120
    1180824 120
    1180825 120
    1180826 120
    1180827 120
    1180828 120
    1180829 120
    1180830 120
    1180831 120
    1180832 120
    1180833 120
    1180834 120
    1180835 120
    1180836 120
    1180837 120
    1180838 rows × 1 columns
```

The output after applying the answer from @RafaelC

```
    test
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
13  1
14  1
15  1
16  1
17  1
18  1
19  1
20  1
21  1
22  1
23  1
24  1
25  1
26  1
27  1
28  1
29  1
... ...
1180808 120
1180809 120
1180810 120
1180811 120
1180812 120
1180813 120
1180814 120
1180815 120
1180816 120
1180817 120
1180818 120
1180819 120
1180820 120
1180821 120
1180822 120
1180823 120
1180824 120
1180825 120
1180826 120
1180827 120
1180828 120
1180829 120
1180830 120
1180831 120
1180832 120
1180833 120
1180834 120
1180835 120
1180836 120
1180837 120
1180838 rows × 1 columns
```

Not sure if there is some type issue in the column, I applied conversion of the column to int64, but still did not resolve the issue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Adam, Warm Welcome to the SO , but  you need to provide the bare minimum details to get the answers  like few line of your DataFrame to see how it looks and the desired output you are looking as it may be easy one to get when you are looking for indeed.

Comment: This is very confusing. Perhaps consider writing a new question, more high level that describes what you want to achieve. with it share a piece of example code with an input that someone else could run to see what you want to do. and share the desired out as @pygo said

Comment: Next time, I will provide a better-structured question. Thank you! The answer provided answers my question, although I now have a different issue with the answer not working on my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible example:

```
MAX = 4
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.repeat(np.arange(1,MAX), 3).tolist()*3})
```

Then, using `diff()`, `cumsum()` and some simple arithmetics

```
D = 1 - (MAX-1)
n = df4.col.diff().eq(D).cumsum()*(MAX-1) + df4.col
```

---

The reproducible example is

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    3
16    3
17    3
18    1
19    1
20    1
21    2
22    2
23    2
24    3
25    3
26    3
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

and the output is

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     4
10    4
11    4
12    5
13    5
14    5
15    6
16    6
17    6
18    7
19    7
20    7
21    8
22    8
23    8
24    9
25    9
26    9
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! The code you created replicates the data I am working with. When I test the code, I now have a different issue. When I apply the code to my dataset https://www.dropbox.com/s/h17ssdu7lgwydd9/compiled_training_data.csv?dl=0, the operation actually does not work. Will show the code in the updated question.